# Unable to load package information from registry: The "timeout" argument must be of type number. Received type string ('200000')

Tags: node.js, angular, angular-material

Unable to load package information from registry: The "timeout" argument must be of type number. Received type string ('200000')

My Node version v16.14.0.
Angular Version  16.1.3

Hi I am trying to install Angular material but i am getting this error

Unable to load package information from registry: The "timeout" argument must be of type number. Received type string ('200000')

My Node version v16.14.0.
Angular Version  16.1.3

Comment: Upgrade your node to v18